# Java method with threads invocation and return in the end

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I have created a simple class in Java with a method that invoke 2 thread (each thread has a simple loop with a println and a pause in each iteration).
In the method "mymethod" I've created and started my two threads.
Between Threads invocation, I've placed two prints. Print occur before threads end, and I assume that the order is as follows:

1. first print
2. first thread start
3. second thread start
4. second print
5. third print

Why the last instruction is executed only when all threads finish their computation instead to return 0 (last instruction)?
Obviously I know that this makes sense, but the return is an instruction like all others? Is the JVM that preventing the return if not all threads are finished yet?

```
public class Main {

public int mymethod (){
    System.out.println("start");

    Th t1 = new Th(); //this is a my thread instance
    t1.start();
    System.out.println("started th1");
    Th t2 = new Th();
    t2.start();
    System.out.println("started th2");
    System.out.println("Finished");
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

    Main m = new Main();
    m.mymethod();
}
```

}

```
This is the output:

start
started th1
started th2
Finished
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html says: The Java virtual machine terminates when all started non-daemon threads have terminated. You started non-daemon threads, and observed this in practice.

Comment: The `return` happens immediately, but the program doesn't end just because you return from `main()`. As Lesiak said, the program, i.e. the JVM, terminates when all non-daemon threads have ended. Normally, the main thread is the only such thread, so normally the program ends when `main` returns, but that changes once you begin starting extra threads.

Comment: It should also be noted that the output is not synchronized, i.e. the order in which the output appears in the console may not be the order in which the output was written to the console. For example, it could be that the first `0` was written to `System.out` well before `started th1`, `started th2` or `Finished`.